# Linking errors… but the library is linked

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, sqlite, linker

VS2008 is giving me multiple linker errors relating to sqlite3 functions... but sqlite3.lib and sqlite3d.lib have both been included as "Additional Dependancies" for the project. Recompiling doesn't solve the problem, and these the libraries listed are the first additional dependencies for the project.

Any thoughts as to what would cause this?

> adding resource. type:STRING, name:10, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:1966
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:11, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:162
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:19, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:428
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:20, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:2406
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:22, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:2048
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:21, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:2360
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:8, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:2232
>
> adding resource. type:STRING, name:9, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:1608
>
> Tools.lib(DataTools.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_exec referenced in ...
>
> Tools.lib(ConfigTools.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_exec
>
> Tools.lib(DataTools.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_open referenced in ...
>
> Tools.lib(ConfigTools.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_open
>
> Tools.lib(DataTools.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_close referenced in ...
>
> Tools.lib(ConfigTools.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_close
>
> Tools.lib(DataTools.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_free_table referenced in ...
>
> Tools.lib(ConfigTools.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_free_table
>
> Tools.lib(DataTools.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_get_table referenced in ...
>
> Tools.lib(ConfigTools.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_get_table

Comment: Why you put them in "Additional Dependencies" and not in the actual lib list in linker settings may have something to do with this. And you should only need one of those as i recall, the `*d.lib` is for debug builds. sans-d is for release.

Comment: So you added the additional library directory (wherever your sqlite3/lib folder is) *and* added the .lib to the library inputs list for your current build configuration? I only ask because that is *exactly* how my sqlite3 client project is configured and I have no such issue. The only time i've ever *seen* a similar issue (didn't experience myself) was a 32bit lib being linked in a 64bit project (it may have been vice-versa, not that it matters).

Comment: I did indeed.

This isn't my first, (or 10th for that matter) project making use of sqlite. As far as I can tell, the library/header usage is exactly the same as it always is, hence my confusion.

Comment: How odd. My interest is peaked. Tools.lib is a separate static lib built with sqlite3 headers, and you're bringing it into this project (some exe or dll) and adding the sqlite libs to the dll/exe project, not the static Tools.lib project, right? (sorry for what may be remedial questions, I can see its not your first rodeo, but if I can't help solve this at least someone else that comes by will know all these bases have already been covered and have a starting gate further down the road). You may as well crank up link verbosity in linker settings to get a better picture of what may be missing.

Comment: Correct. DataTools and ConfigTools are both classes defined within the Tools.lib project and make use of functions prototyped in sqlite.h. The project I'm attempting to link (Let's call it ToolsUser for simplicity) has the sqlite3.lib and Tools.lib both listed as dependencies. (in that order). As far as I can tell, there should be no issue linking the Tools.lib calls back to the sqlite3 lib. I'll change the linker verbosity and see what it gives me.

Comment: As near as I can tell, Mike, you're absolutely right. There should be no issues at all given what you describe. It definitely sounds like you played out the usual scenarios (I know that feeling of wtf-rising-frustration, believe me). I hope its something simple. When you crank up the linker output verbosity to see what is being searched, banged-on for link, etc, if it isn't too hideous, you may want to add that output to your question text as additional info.

Comment: Output of linker with /VERBOSE set edited in... Nothing interesting, just a bunch of string resources being loaded.

In an equally baffling turn of events, loading an earlier version of the ToolsUser.proj (which has only code changes) complies fine with the same libraries... Merging in the code changes from the newer version of ToolsUser resulted in no linking errors.

I blame goblins.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, nice to know it's not just my slightly inebriated self missing something obvious. I'm just going to run with the merged version of the project and blame black magic for this one. I'm curious as to what the hell is going on, but 90 minutes is past my threshold for trying to figure out what the hell is going on when I'm on a deadline.